# Interface in Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

Learning Kotlin, i want to realize interface on adapter, which will be notify activity when item was clicked. Nothing works, i need your help.

If i write Java, i make it this way:(interface: `OnAnimalClickListener`):

Adapter:

```
public class PackContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PackContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private OnAnimalClickListener onAnimalClickListener;
    ...
    void setOnAnimalClickListener(OnAnimalClickListener onAnimalClickListener) {
        this.onAnimalClickListener = onAnimalClickListener;
    }
    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.bind(item);
    }
    ...
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ...
        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ...
        }

        void bind(Item item) {
            ...             
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onAnimalClickListener.onAnimalClicked();
        }
    }

    public interface OnAnimalClickListener {
        void onAnimalClicked();
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
contentAdapter.setOnAnimalClickListener(() -> //doSomething);
```

This i write on Kotlin(names changed):

Adapter:

```
class PacksAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PacksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var onPackClickListener: OnPackClickListener? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }

    var packList: ArrayList<Animal> = ArrayList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cell_animalpack_4, parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(packList[0], context)
    }


 class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view),View.OnClickListener {
        ...
        fun bind(pack: AnimalPackFull, context: Context) {
            ...
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            onPackClickListener.
        }
    }

    interface OnPackClickListener {
        fun onPackClicked(packId: Int)
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
(recycler_packs.adapter as PacksAdapter).onPackClickListener = PacksAdapter.OnPackClickListener()
```

My questions:

1) I specifically don't complete my code here:

```
 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                onPackClickListener.
            }
```

Because of i don't see my `onPackClickListener` from onClick, IDE write that it `Unresolved`. Why?

2) I got en Error on Activity:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

I can understand, what i do wrong?

Comment: exactly like in java, interfaces in kotlin can't be directly instantiated.

Comment: Make your `var onPackClickListener` **internal**. *(I.e. `internal var onPackClickListener: OnPackClickListener? = null`)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will see your `onPackClickListener` only if you declare the nested class as `inner` class (see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html).

However, I suggest to pass the listener to the `ViewHolder` class as an argument and call that parameter, something like this:

```
inner class ViewHolder(view: View, itemClickListener: OnPackClickListener?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {

    fun bind(pack: AnimalPackFull, context: Context) { ... }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        onPackClickListener?.onPackClicked(...)
    }
}
```

Another problem is that you have to create that interface by implementing it becuase you can't just create an instance of it:

```
val listener = object : OnPackClickListener {
        override fun onPackClicked(packId: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented")
        }
    }
```

A suggestion here. A nice thing about Kotlin is that you can switch single method interfaces to lambdas (see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html).
The code can be refactored to something like this:

```
class PacksAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<PacksAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

var onPackClickListener: ((Int) ->Unit)? = null
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }

var packList: ArrayList<Animal> = ArrayList()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cell_animalpack_4, parent, false), onPackClickListener)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(packList[0], context)
}


class ViewHolder(view: View, private val itemClickListener: ((Int) ->Unit)?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {

    fun bind(pack: AnimalPackFull, context: Context) { ... }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        itemClickListener?.invoke(...)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Its more easy to use kotlin callback:

In your adapter:

```
    class LEventsAdapter(
    private val items: MutableList<EventDetailItem> = ArrayList(),
    private val callback: (id: String, distance: String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LEventsAdapter.LEventsViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

 ...
```

In your viewholder in onclick call : `callback.invoke(id, distance)`

And in your activity implement your callback:

```
recView.adapter = LEventsAdapter(items, callback = { id, distance -> 
  //your code here
})
```